# What's the meaning of "It's amazing what you can store without refrigeration nowadays."?

Tags: grammar

> It's amazing what you can store without refrigeration nowadays.

Are they saying #1 or #2 ?

1. The fact that you can store without refrigeration is amazing.
2. The things you can store without refrigeration is amazing.

And, could you be so kind to find a fitting dictionary entry for the usage of 'what' here for me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question perhaps lies somewhere between your two suggestions.

> It's amazing what you can store without refrigeration nowadays.

Note that it says "it's amazing **what** you can store", and not "amazing **that** you can store (items) without refrigeration".

It is neither just the fact that things can be stored without refrigeration, nor the items themselves that are "amazing". Rather, the person is amazed at fact that *specific* items can be stored without refrigeration.

The [dictionary definition](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/what) of "what" being used here is:

> relative determiner
>   (referring to the whole of an amount) whatever.